# Azure Key Vault get Secret from VMSS Instances

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Does someone have a solution to get a Azure Key Vault Secret from a VMSS Instance? 
For a single VM I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-python-linux-virtual-machine#create-edit-and-run-the-sample-python-app

Can I do something similar like that for a VMSS Instance? 
With the Python Script from the Microsoft Documentation I have the following issue. I can't reach the Key Vault URL from the Instance with this Request. (Request Timeout.)

```
requests.get(url = KeyVaultURL, headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + data["access_token"]})
```

The VMSS has a LoadBalancer with a Public IP Address. 
And the Instances in the Backendpool have only one NIC (Private IP). 
The Vault and the VMSS are in different Resource Groups.

Do you have any idea why i cant reach the Key Vault from my Instances?
Because if the Identity (Access Policy) would be the problem, i should get a 4xx and not a timeout.

Thanks 
KR

Comment: why not? what have you tried?

Comment: I tried exactly this python script on my VMSS Instance. But I can't reach my Key Vault. (Connection Timeout.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you assign a managed identity to vmss through portal and test it again it should work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vmss

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. 
But i guess the identity shouldn't be the issue. 
Because I can use the VMSS Identity to create a new Access Policy in my Azure Key Vault.

Comment: then it should be some issue in the NSG. Try adding a service endpoint and see if it works: az network vnet subnet update --resource-group "myresourcegroup" --vnet-name "myvnet" --name "mysubnet" --service-endpoints "Microsoft.KeyVault"

Comment: Thanks the problem is fixed when I add a service endpoint to the subnet.